# Smallest positive integer solution to $\tan{19x} = \frac{\cos{96} + \sin{96}}{\cos{96} - \sin{96}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math

> Find the smallest positive integer solution to $\tan{19x°} = \frac{\cos{96°} + \sin{96°}}{\cos{96°} - \sin{96°}}.$

The solution states to use $\sin(\theta) = \cos(90-\theta)$ and simplify the fraction to $-\cot{51}$, then use some number theory to finish it off.

---

My approach:

We can use difference of squares on the RHS.
\begin{align}
  &\frac{(\cos{96°} + \sin{96°})(\cos{96°} - \sin{96°})}{(\cos{96°} - \sin{96°})^2} = \\
  &\qquad\frac{\cos^2{96°}-\sin^2{96°}}{\cos^2{96°}+\sin^2{96°}-2\cos{96°}\sin{96°}} = \frac{\cos{192°}}{1-\sin{192°}}.
\end{align}

However, finding the value for this is hard. I did note the resemblance of the half-angle tangent formula. It states that for any angle $\theta$, $$\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{1+\cos{\theta}} = \frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}.$$

My question is, can $\frac{\cos{192°}}{1-\sin{192°}}$ be used in any way to relate to the half-angle tangent formula? An added bonus is that we want to find $\tan{19x}$, and having a tangent formula only helps. However, I was unable to find a relation.

*Problem from 1996 AIME Problem 10. The official solution is linked [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1996_AIME_Problems/Problem_10).*

Comment: Maybe you can use $96=4 \cdot 19 +1$? (Or not, just glanced at the key!)

Comment: Substitute $\sin 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1+\tan^2x}$ and $\cos 2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align} 
\frac{\cos(192°)}{1 - \sin(192°)} 
& = \frac{\sin(90° - 192°)}{1 - \cos(90° - 192°)} \\
& = \frac{\sin258°}{1 - \cos258°} \\
& = \frac{1}{\frac{1 - \cos258°}{\sin258°}} \\
& = \frac{1}{\tan(\frac{258°}{2})} \\
& = \frac{1}{\tan129°} \\\\
& = \tan(270° - 129°) \\\\
& = \tan141°
\end{align}

It suffices to find smallest positive x such that
$$ 19x \equiv 141 \pmod {180}$$
notice that $19^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {180}$, thus
\begin{align}
x &\equiv 19 \cdot 141 \\
&\equiv 159\pmod{180}
\end{align}
The smallest positive $x$ is thus $159$.

Comment: $141$ is not an integer multiple of $19$

Answer (score 2):

A mush simpler manipulation, in my opinion, using addition formulae
$$
\frac{\cos y+\sin y}{\cos y-\sin y}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(y+45^\circ)}{\sqrt{2}\cos(y+45^\circ)}=\tan(y+45^\circ)
$$
then, for $y=96^\circ,$
$$
19^\circ x=141^\circ+180^\circ k,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$